# Why are my @components not detected by spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

This one is tricky - for me at least.Component scan does not seem to work

Here is the web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
    <display-name>Geomajas GWT face example application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:org/geomajas/spring/geomajasContext.xml
            classpath:org/geomajas/plugin/rasterizing/DefaultRasterizedPipelines.xml
            WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
<!--            WEB-INF/applicationContext2.xml -->
<!--            WEB-INF/layer*.xml -->
<!--            WEB-INF/map*.xml -->
            WEB-INF/layerOsm.xml
            WEB-INF/mapOsm.xml
<!--            WEB-INF/applicationContext2.xml -->

       </param-value>
    </context-param>



    <filter>
        <filter-name>CacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.geomajas.servlet.CacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CacheFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.geomajas.servlet.PrepareScanningContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GeomajasServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.geomajas.gwt.server.GeomajasServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath*:META-INF/geomajasWebContext.xml</param-value>
            <description>Spring Web-MVC specific (additional) context files.</description>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<!-- SpringGwt remote service servlet --> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>contexConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext2.xml</param-value>
        <description>j</description>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GeomajasServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/showcase/geomajasService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/d/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springGwtRemoteServiceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/showcase/springGwtServices/test</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

And my service :

```
@Service("test")
public class ProjServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ProjService {
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ProjServiceImpl.class);



    @Autowired
    PoiCategDAO poiCategDAO;

    public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // Verify that the input is valid. 
        if (!FieldVerifier.isValidName(input)) {
            // If the input is not valid, throw an IllegalArgumentException back to
            // the client.
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Name must be at least 4 characters long");
        }
        //RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request);
//      String serverInfo = getServletContext().getServerInfo();
//      String userAgent = getThreadLocalRequest().getHeader("User-Agent");



        return "Hello, " + input + "!<br><br>I am running .<br><br>It looks like you are using:<br>";
        }

    @Override
    //@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void testdao(Integer id) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PoiCateg X=poiCategDAO.findById(id);    
    PoiCateg z=poiCategDAO.findById(id);
    }

}
```

And applicaationContext2.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="ne.projl.*" />
<!--    <context:component-scan base-package="FULLY QUALIFIED" /> -->

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPUnit" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Please note that if i put context:component-scan  in applicationContext.xml ( not applicatinContext2.xml my service bean is detected. ). If there's other info i should provide do tell.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by your last sentence: source code you quoted is applicationContext2.xml and it contains component-scan.  And you said applicationContext.xml contains component-scan but not applicationContext2.xml.  Even more messy is, your web.xml is referring to application.xml.  Can you simplify and clean up your question first?

Comment: What method you use to determine your bean is scanned or not?

Comment: hold on, does your last sentence actually: if i put context:component-scan in applicationContext.xml ( not applicationContext2.xml) my service bean is detected.  ??  If so, that's obvious: applicationContext2.xml is not used in Spring. You haven't included that in web.xml's contextConfigLocation

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, base package in component scan only requires a package name.  Then all underlying sub-package will be included.

Therefore the correct setting should be

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ne.projl" />
```

Comment: 1. Is your application context xml really loaded? 2. Is your service really under ne.projl? 3. it should be without '.*' but not without '*'.  4. Have you tried to make a simplest project with only one main class, one service class and load the application context in your main method? Make sure you really know how to use it, before quoting lots of irrelevant information here

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reason, one common reason is you created your `@Component` class under wrong package.

As your context scanning config set the Class has to be under this package

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ne.projl.*" />
```

Comment: ne.projl is my base package. Just checked for misspellings and all my classes are under ne.projl.someothername

Answer (score 0):

Posting the exception (if any) would provide  more insight in to the issue for everyone here. Looks to me like a visibility problem.
If you are referencing to a component that is scanned in your applicationContext2, in one of your components that is loaded via contextConfigLocation, obviously it wont be visible. 
.[check this link for more info on visibility of application context](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/07/09/spring-web-application-context-visibility/)
. I could not add a comment to the question..so i have posted my observations as answer.. Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but does not your web.xml says  this

```
<!--            WEB-INF/applicationContext2.xml -->
```

is'nt that commented out ?

are you doing an import resource of applicationContext2 in applicationContext.xml file ?